# How do I know the font size (for example) of a specific piece of text in a word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

The idea is simple, but the answer may get complicated:

In fact, I can check the run properties for the font size.

If absent I need to check the style applied to the paragraph in order to find the run properties defined for the font size, then that style's paragraph run properties.

If not found I need to check everything again regarding the style which this style is based on.

If not found, I should check the following style going up in the style hierarchy, and go on till I reach the default style.

I also need to check if the previous paragraph has a style applied to it. In this case the applied style may define the style for the next paragraph that affects the text I'm working with.

If there is no style influencing my paragraph, then I need to look in the default run properties from the styles part. After that I should look to the default paragraph properties in the same part.

If nothing applies then the responsibility for the size defintion goes into the application that is working with the document.

Am I right?

Don't I have any help from OPenXML SDK and/or from OpenXmlPowerTools?

An important aspect is that this question extends to almost any paragraph or run property besides text font size.

My ultimate goal is to find out if a piece of text is a section header (like heading1, heading2, etc.) based on formatting but it looks difficult to get tsomething so simple as "the current formatting of a piece of text". To get things harder I also need to deal with (section) numbering that many times doesn't have a numbering format applied to the paragraph.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this required to be solved using the openxml-sdk? Or would a solution based on the Word Interop API be applicable?

Comment: Word Interop-API shouldn't be used.

Comment: I have a partcial answer from Eric White ( http://www.ericwhite.com/ ):
"At the moment, there are no good examples for this in either the Open XML SDK or in PowerTools."
So, I have to work on the solution. It mmay take same time. After that I will post the results.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So, I'm answering my own question as promised.

I developed a method that returns the "effective" run properties of a specific run from a word document paragraph. It takes into account the default document properties, applied styles including the related style hierarchy and the direct run properties according to the standard - ISO/IEC29500-1.

It is interesting to note that Word doesn't seem to follow completely the standard in these two aspects:
1 - If a paragraph has no style applied to it, word applies the default paragraph style. As far as I know I think that no style should be applied. This doesn't happen for a run: when a run has no run style, the default run style is not applied.
2 - In order to get the effective run properties it is necessary to "roll-up styles". Paragraph styles and run styles follow a style hierarchy. In order to get a specific property value it is necessary to look for it in the applied style, if not present look for it in the parent style and so on. A property that is defined with a specific value in a certain style shouldn't be added to the child style if it has the same value. Word doesn't follow this rule for character styles. In fact all run properties applied from the run style can be obtained directly for that run style without being necessary to follow the style hierarchy. This is not according to the standard.

Now, let me go into some details of my solution:

First, my code uses the openxml power tools:
http://powertools.codeplex.com/

Next, for rolling up styles regarding the style inheritance I adapted and implemented the solution provided by Eric White at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/12/13/implementing-inheritance-in-xml.aspx
and
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/10/29/open-xml-wordprocessingml-style-inheritance.aspx

The complete algorithm for getting the run properties can be found in the standard and it is also provided by Eric White at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/11/12/assembling-paragraph-and-run-properties-for-cells-in-a-table.aspx
In this case it regards the extraction of properties from a cell inside a table. My method doesn't work for paragraphs inside tables (I just don't need it :-) ) but it can be extended to deal with these cases (all information is in Eric's article)

Please note that I deal properly with toggle properties and the way word really works (the points I made for the differences related with the standard.

Finaly, the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class OpenXmlPowerToolsUtilities
    {
        public static XElement GetEffectiveRunProperties(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, XElement run)
        {
            XElement runProperties = null;
            List<XElement> runPropertiesList = new List<XElement>();

            XElement paragraph = run.Parent;
            if (paragraph.Name != W.p)
                return null;

            StyleDefinitionsPart styleDefinitionsPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart
                .StyleDefinitionsPart;
            if (styleDefinitionsPart == null)
                return null;
            XElement styles = styleDefinitionsPart.GetXDocument().Root;           

            // 1 - Get run default
            XElement runDefault = styles.Elements(W.docDefaults)
                .Elements(W.rPrDefault)
                .Elements(W.rPr)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (runDefault != null)
                runPropertiesList.Add(runDefault);

            // 2 - get paragraph style run properties
            XElement pStyleRunProperties = null;
            string pStyle = (string)paragraph.Elements(W.pPr)
                .Elements(W.pStyle)
                .Attributes(W.val)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (pStyle != null)
            {
                pStyleRunProperties = AssembleStyleInformation(styles, pStyle)
                                                       .Elements(W.rPr)
                                                       .FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                XElement defaultParagraphStyle = styles
                                        .Elements(W.style)
                                        .Where(e =>
                                            (string)e.Attribute(W.type) == "paragraph" &&
                                               (string)e.Attribute(W._default) == "1")
                                        .Select(s => s)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
                pStyleRunProperties = defaultParagraphStyle.Elements(W.rPr).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            if (pStyleRunProperties != null)
                runPropertiesList.Add(pStyleRunProperties);

            // 3 - get run style run properties
            string rStyle = (string)run.Elements(W.rPr).Elements(W.rStyle).Attributes(W.val).FirstOrDefault();
            XElement rStyleRunProperties = null;
            if (rStyle != null)
            {
                rStyleRunProperties = AssembleStyleInformation(styles, rStyle)
                                                       .Elements(W.rPr)
                                                       .FirstOrDefault();
            }
            if (rStyleRunProperties != null)
                runPropertiesList.Add(rStyleRunProperties);

            XElement toggleProperties = AssembleToggleProperties(runDefault, pStyleRunProperties, rStyleRunProperties);
            if (toggleProperties != null)
                runPropertiesList.Add(toggleProperties);

            // 4 - direct run properties
            XElement directRunProperties = run.Elements(W.rPr).FirstOrDefault();
            if (directRunProperties != null)
                runPropertiesList.Add(directRunProperties);

            runProperties = AssembleRunProperties(runPropertiesList);

            return runProperties;
        }

        private static XElement AssembleRunProperties(List<XElement> runPropertiesList)
        {
            return runPropertiesList
                .Aggregate(
                    new XElement(W.rPr,
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w)),
                    (mergedRun, run) =>
                        MergeChildElements(mergedRun, run));
        }

        static XElement AssembleToggleProperties(XElement runDefault, XElement pStyleRunProperties, XElement rStyleRunProperties)
        {
            XElement runToggleProperties;

            runToggleProperties = new XElement(W.rPr, 
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w));

            foreach (XName toggleProperty in toggleProperties)
            {
                XElement runDefaultToggleProperty = runDefault.Elements(toggleProperty).FirstOrDefault();

                if (runDefaultToggleProperty != null)
                {
                    if ((string)runDefaultToggleProperty.Attributes(W.val).FirstOrDefault() != "0")
                    {
                        runToggleProperties.Add(runDefaultToggleProperty);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                XElement pStyleToggleProperty = null;
                if (pStyleRunProperties == null)
                    pStyleToggleProperty = null;
                else
                    pStyleToggleProperty = pStyleRunProperties.Elements(toggleProperty).FirstOrDefault();

                XElement rStyleToggleProperty = null;
                if (rStyleRunProperties == null)
                    rStyleToggleProperty = null;
                else
                    rStyleToggleProperty = rStyleRunProperties.Elements(toggleProperty).FirstOrDefault();

                if (pStyleToggleProperty == null && rStyleToggleProperty != null)
                    runToggleProperties.Add(rStyleToggleProperty);
                else if (pStyleToggleProperty != null && rStyleToggleProperty == null)
                    runToggleProperties.Add(pStyleToggleProperty);
                else if (pStyleToggleProperty != null && rStyleToggleProperty != null)
                {
                    if ((string)rStyleToggleProperty.Attributes(W.val).FirstOrDefault() == "0")
                        runToggleProperties.Add(pStyleToggleProperty);
                    else if ((string)pStyleToggleProperty.Attributes(W.val).FirstOrDefault() == "0")
                        runToggleProperties.Add(rStyleToggleProperty);
                    else
                        runToggleProperties.Add(new XElement(toggleProperty, new XAttribute(W.val, "0")));
                }
            }

            return runToggleProperties;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<XElement> StyleChainReverseOrder(XElement styles, string styleId)
        {
            string current = styleId;
            while (true)
            {
                XElement style = styles.Elements(W.style)
                    .Where(s => (string)s.Attribute(W.styleId) == current).FirstOrDefault();
                yield return style;
                current = (string)style.Elements(W.basedOn).Attributes(W.val).FirstOrDefault();
                if (current == null)
                    yield break;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<XElement> StyleChain(XElement styles, string styleId)
        {
            return StyleChainReverseOrder(styles, styleId).Reverse();
        }

        private static XElement AssembleStyleInformation(XElement styles, string styleId)
        {
            return StyleChain(styles, styleId)
                .Aggregate(
                    new XElement(W.style, new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w)),
                    (mergedStyle, style) => MergeChildElements(mergedStyle, style));
        }

        public static XName[] Others =
        {
            W.pStyle,
            W.rStyle
        };

        public static XName[] ElementsWithMergeElementsSemantics =
        {
            W.style,
            W.rPr,
            W.pPr 
        };

        public static XName[] ElementsWithMergeAttributesSemantics =
        {
            W.ind,
            W.spacing,
            W.lang
        };

        public static XName[] ElementsWithReplaceElementsSemantics =
        {
            W.name, // The style Name element
            W.adjustRightInd,
            W.autoSpaceDE,
            W.autoSpaceDN,
            W.bidi,
            W.cnfStyle,  // within a table
            W.contextualSpacing,
            W.divId, 
            W.framePr,
            W.jc,
            W.keepLines,
            W.keepNext,
            W.kinsoku,
            W.mirrorIndents,
            W.numPr,
            W.outlineLvl,
            W.overflowPunct,
            W.pageBreakBefore,
            W.pBdr,  
            W.shd,
            W.snapToGrid,
            W.suppressAutoHyphens,
            W.suppressLineNumbers,
            W.suppressOverlap,
            W.tabs,  
            W.textAlignment,
            W.textboxTightWrap,  // within a textbox
            W.textDirection,
            W.topLinePunct,
            W.widowControl,
            W.wordWrap,
            W.b,
            W.bCs,
            W.bdr,
            W.caps,
            W.color,
            W.cs,
            W.dstrike,
            W.eastAsianLayout,
            W.effect,
            W.em,
            W.emboss,
            W.fitText,
            W.highlight,
            W.i,
            W.iCs,
            W.imprint,
            W.kern,
            W.noProof,
            W.oMath,
            W.outline,
            W.position,
            W.rFonts,
            W.rtl,
            W.shadow,
            W.shd,
            W.smallCaps,
            W.snapToGrid,
            //W.spacing,   // different from paragraph spacing
            W.specVanish,
            W.strike,
            W.sz,
            W.szCs,
            W.u,  
            W.vanish,
            W.vertAlign,
            W._w, 
            W.webHidden           
        };

        public static XName[] toggleProperties =
        {
            W.b,
            W.bCs,
            W.caps,
            W.emboss,
            W.i,
            W.iCs,
            W.imprint,
            W.outline,
            W.shadow,
            W.smallCaps,
            W.strike,
            W.vanish
        };

        public static bool IsValidMergeElement(XName name)
        {
            if (ElementsWithMergeAttributesSemantics.Contains(name) ||
                ElementsWithMergeElementsSemantics.Contains(name) ||
                ElementsWithReplaceElementsSemantics.Contains(name))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public static bool IsToggleProperty(XName name)
        {
            if (toggleProperties.Contains(name))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public static bool HasReplaceSemantics(XName name)
        {
            if (ElementsWithReplaceElementsSemantics.Contains(name))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public static bool HasMergeElementsSemantics(XName name)
        {
            if (ElementsWithMergeElementsSemantics.Contains(name))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public static bool HasMergeAttributesSemantics(XName name)
        {
            if (ElementsWithMergeAttributesSemantics.Contains(name))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public static XElement MergeChildElements(XElement mergedElement, XElement element)
        {
            if (mergedElement == null || element == null)
            {
                if (element == null)
                    element = mergedElement;
                XElement newElement = new XElement(element.Name,
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w),
                    element.Attributes()
                   .Where(a =>
                   {
                       if (a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                           return false;
                       if (element.Name == W.style)
                           if (!(a.Name == W.type || a.Name == W.styleId))
                               return false;
                       return true;
                   }),
                element.Elements().Select(e =>
                {
                    if (e.Name == W.rPr || e.Name == W.pPr)
                        return MergeChildElements(null, e);

                    if (IsValidMergeElement(e.Name))
                        return e;

                    return null;
                }));
                return newElement;
            }

            XElement newMergedElement = new XElement(element.Name,
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w),
                element.Attributes()
                   .Where(a =>
                   {
                       if (a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                           return false;
                       if (element.Name == W.style)
                           if (!(a.Name == W.type || a.Name == W.styleId))
                               return false;
                       return true;
                   }),
                element.Elements().Select(e =>
                {
                    if (HasReplaceSemantics(e.Name))
                        return e;

                    // spacing within run properties has replace semantics 
                    if (element.Name == W.rPr && e.Name == W.spacing)
                        return e;

                    if (HasMergeAttributesSemantics(e.Name))
                    {
                        XElement newElement;
                        newElement = new XElement(e.Name,
                            e.Attributes(),
                            mergedElement.Elements(e.Name).Attributes()
                                .Where(a =>
                                    !(e.Attributes().Any(z => z.Name == a.Name))));
                        return newElement;
                    }

                    if (e.Name == W.rPr || e.Name == W.pPr)
                    {
                        XElement correspondingElement = mergedElement.Element(e.Name);
                        return MergeChildElements(correspondingElement, e);
                    }
                    return null;
                }),
                mergedElement.Elements()
                    .Where(m => !element.Elements(m.Name).Any()));

            return newMergedElement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use a similar approach for PowerPoint? I'm trying to set the font typeface for all the runs that don't have one set. I think I need to follow the font selection process http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeinteroperability/archive/2013/04/22/office-open-xml-themes-schemes-and-fonts.aspx